# How can I access $(this) inside a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, this

I have the following click event

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    var idNum = $(this).getID;
    $('#new-'+idNum).fadeIn();      
});
```

and the following function:

```
function getID() {
    var elID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    return elID;
}
```

What I want is to be able to click on `.element`, get it's parent's ID, and then store that ID in the variable `idNum`.  But this doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).getID()` to invoke the function. Right now you're assigning a reference to the function to `idNum`, not the result of a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this code in another function, why don't you just do it in the same one?

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    var idNum = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#new-'+idNum).fadeIn();  

    getID(idNum);   
});

function getID(idNum) {
    var newObject = $(body).find(idNum);
    //Do stuff with newObject
}
```

Since you can't pass $(this) natively (it's an object built into jQuery), you could instead search the DOM for the existence of a variable you pass (like the above code does).

Comment: getID is a larger function that I just simplified for the sake of this question.  Sorry, I should have noted that.

Comment: My changed answer should reflect what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to pass $(this) into the function itself, do some processing, and then store the return in a var within the click function?  I know that what you're proposing will work, I'd just like to know how to do this for future reference.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't actually pass the $(this) object, that's native to jQuery.  However, you should reach the same effect by passing the ID of that object into the function, then searching the DOM for it.  See my edited post above.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an extra function at all? Just do:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    var idNum = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#new-'+idNum).fadeIn();      
});
```